# How can I make my Voice Assistant launch the apps?

Tags: python-3.8

I am working on a Voice Assistant.
I need to allow it to launch apps, how can be found the path of the apps to launch them?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite minimal but I can attempt to answer it for you.

Assuming that you're using windows 10, with Word for example, you would type in word using the indexing feature at the bottom left of your desktop. Then you would click the down arrow to reveal more options. Then you would click open file location. The address at the top of your explorer will show the file location.

If you want to open another exe (or compatible software) in a known location but is not available to index, you would open your explorer and navigate to the desired application. Copy paste the address at the top of the explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

You should import `subprocess` to your code and when you need to open the app write `subprocess.check_output("file location", shell=True)`
For example:

```py
subprocess.check_output("C:\\Test\\Test\\Test\\application.exe(or .lnk or  something u need)", shell=True)
```